# What's wrong with this RxUI code?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm new to RxUI and i dont know why onComplete is not invoked on this code:

```
Refresh = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask( o =>  studentsService.Students(Status, SearchText));

 Refresh.Subscribe(studs =>
        {
            Students.Clear();
            foreach (var stud in studs)
                Students.Add(stud);               
        }, exception => DebugHelper.WriteException(exception), 
        async () =>
        {
           //this is never invoked???
            foreach (var student in Students)
                student.PhotoIdentity = (await studentsService.Pic(student.StudentGuid));               
        });
```

signature of studentsService.Students() :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> Students(List<StudentStatus> status, string searchString = default(string),  int take = 30, int skip = 0)
```

Comment: You would need to provide the definition of `Refresh`. There's nothing in a `.Subscribe(...)` method that tells you if any of the lambdas actually get called. If it were `Observable.Never<Student>()` you'd never get anything.

Comment: You might have to keep going deeper into that rabbit hole. That code doesn't show anything that could be helpful either.

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question with enough code for us to run and see your error I'm afraid. None of the code you've posted shows why the `OnComplete` isn't being called.

Comment: You shouldn't delete your comments. They provide context to other's comments and the changes in your question.

Comment: Also, we still need to be able to actually run your code. You should post enough code for us to copy and paste to a console app and run it. Unless you can demonstrate your problem we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subscribing to a `ReactiveCommand`, you'll be notified once per execution of said command, and this observable stream will never complete (as the command could be executed at any time).

Hence the behavior you're noticing is as expected, maybe you simply need to move your OnComplete code to the OnNext part ?